# Extract numbers from AT command in Arduino

Tags: arduino, at-command, esp32

So I'm doing an AT command and the reply is

```
AT+CGDCONT?
+CGDCONT: 1,"IP","hologram","0.0.0.0",0,0,0,0
+CGDCONT: 13,"IP","hologram","0.0.0.0",0,0,0,0
+CGDCONT: 14,"IP","hologram","0.0.0.0",0,0,0,0
OK
```

I need to get the numbers out of this that are written before the "IP" (for this example they are 1,13,14). The numbers range from 1-24 as do the number of lines.

I was reading the reply from the command and saving it as a String with

```cpp
  String input;
  SerialAT.println("AT+CGDCONT?");
  delay(500);
  if (SerialAT.available()) {
    input = SerialAT.readString();
    Serial.println(input);
  }
```

Right now I am reading the stream reply and saving it as a String. The String is then cut at the newline (\n) and stored pieces in an array. After that, I have it read the array and stop once it hits a "," which is right after the number. Then it identifies the section that contains ": " which is right before the number and gets the index position of the ": " and uses that to take a substring of what is left which is just the number.
So for the example that I have, it would put the first row into the array looking like this

```
+CGDCONT: 1,"IP","hologram","0.0.0.0",0,0,0,0
```

It would be read one char at a time until the first "," is identified like this

```
+
+C
+CG
+CGD
+CGDC
+CGDCO
+CGDCON
+CGDCONT
+CGDCONT:
+CGDCONT: 
+CGDCONT: 1
```

then the position of ": " would be identified and for this example, it would be 9. So everything after the 9th position inside of the array would be the output which is 1.

This is working flawlessly and I have even sent in garbled text before the +CGDCONT: because sometimes that's what the modem replies if it didn't have time to fully process the command and it has always fed me the numbers out correctly.

My code for this is

```cpp
  String input;
  SerialAT.println("AT+CGDCONT?");
  delay(500);
  if (SerialAT.available()) {
    input = SerialAT.readString();
    Serial.println(input);
  } else {
    Serial.println("Failed to get PDP!");
  }


  const int numberOfPieces = 10;
  String pieces[numberOfPieces];
  int counter = 0;
  int lastIndex = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
    if (input.substring(i, i + 1) == "\n") {
      pieces[counter] = input.substring(lastIndex, i);
      lastIndex = i + 1;
      counter++;
    }
    if (i == input.length() - 1) {
      pieces[counter] = input.substring(lastIndex, i);
    }
  }

  input = "";
  counter = 0;
  lastIndex = 0;

  String readString, data;
  int D;
  int PDPcounter = 0;

  for ( int i = 0; i < numberOfPieces; i++) {
    for ( int x = 0; x < pieces[i].length(); x++) {
      char c = pieces[i][x];  //gets one byte from buffer
      Serial.println(readString);
      if (c == ',') {
        if (readString.indexOf(": ") >= 0) {
          data = readString.substring((readString.indexOf(": ") + 1));
          D = data.toInt();
          Serial.println(D);
          PDP[PDPcounter] = D;
          Serial.print("PDPcounter = "); Serial.println(PDPcounter);
          PDPcounter++;
          readString = "";
          data = "";
          break;
        }
        readString = "";
        data = "";
      }
      else {
        readString += c;
      }
    }
  }
```

At the very end, I try and read the contents of the PDP array with

```cpp
    for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      Serial.print(i);
      Serial.print(" - ");
      Serial.println(PDP[i]);
    }
```

and I am getting the following

```
0 - 1
1 - 13
2 - 14
3 - 0
4 - 0
5 - 0
6 - 0
7 - 0
8 - 0
9 - 0
```

which is exactly what I need.

---

I guess the only help that I need now is code cleanup recommendations.

Comment: You should try to show your code and explain why it doesn't work or mess, not to just asking people to write  the code for you. BTW, see  https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/StringCharacters